# Failed of genesis!

Tags: genesis-block

fruitd: chainparams.cpp:207: CMainParams::CMainParams(): Assertion `consensus.hashGenesisBlock == uint256S("0x000000004421dbf94542db9b40e4bc60da8ce6b793f00924cadf5677d364a6a1")' failed.
Aborted

used fork emercoin

https://github.com/emercoin/emercoin/blob/master/src/chainparams.cpp

```
return CreateGenesisBlock(pszTimestamp, genesisOutputScript, nTimeTx, nTimeBlock, nNonce, nBits, nVersion, genesisReward);
genesis = CreateGenesisBlock(1533183609, 0, 3712766900, 0x1d00ffff, 1, 0);
```

what is nTimeTx, nTimeBlock and how generate this?

i used this for generates https://github.com/liveblockchain/genesisgen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://github.com/emercoin/emercoin/blob/master/src/primitives/transaction.h

const uint32_t nTime;                    // PPCoin: transaction timestamp

The bitcoin genesis block has a timestamp that is nTime.

For emercoin there seems to be two timestamps, one for the genesis block and one for the coinabase transaction. So in this case nTimeBlock is the original nTime and nTimeTx is the transaction timestamp.

Comment: how to generate transaction timestamp. this from fork or i used emercoin timestamp. but fail like up there. need tools like genesis block?any clue sir. how to generate this.